# does this hold for roots of zero dimensional ideals?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, roots

Given an algebraically closed field $K$ and a zero dimensional ideal $I \subset K[x,y]$ ($1 \notin I$), then there exists a (univariate) polynomial $p \in I \cap K[x]$, s.t. $I \cap K[x] = \left< p\right>$. A necessary condition for a common root $(x_i,y_i)$ of $I$ (i.e. $(x_i,y_i) \in V(I)$) is then, of course, that $x_i$ is a root of $p$.

But what about the reverse direction: can any root $\bar x$ of $p$ be extended to a common root $(\bar x,\bar y)$ of $I$?

It seems obvious that this is true, but I cannot find a proof.

Comment: In general, the irreducible factors of $p$ are the minimal polynomials of $a\in K$ such that there is $b\in K$ with $(a,b)$ a zero of $I$. For an algebraically closed field $K$ these irreducible factors are monic of degree one, and this shows that your guess holds.

Comment: @user26857 can you give me more details or a reference on this property of the irreducible factors of $p$?

Comment: This is standard and follows form the proof that $I\cap K[x]\ne0$ assuming that you know $V(I)$ is finite.

Comment: @user26857 Hm, since $I$ is proper $V(I)$ is not empty (by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz). $I$ being zero dimensional is equivalent to $I \cap K[x] \neq 0 \wedge I \cap K[y] \neq 0$ (which is again equivalent to $V(I)$ being finite). So at least one root of $p$ can be extended to an element in $V(I)$. But I still do not get it why all roots of $p$ appear in $V(I)$.

Comment: I think I was pretty clear: assume that $V(I)$ is finite and try to prove that $I\cap K[x]\ne0$, respectively $I\cap K[y]\ne0$. How do you find a non-zero polynomial in the intersection?

Comment: now I got it - many thanks. So it is the strong Nullstellensatz that asserts that a polynomial factoring only into irreducible polynomials of the roots appearing in $V(I)$ is contained in $I$. Then $p$, dividing this polynomial, has the same property. From the computational point of view (e.g. when computing a Groebner basis) this is kind of magical.